# Evaluation of the dominant mode in a waveguide

Tags: microwave, waveguide

In a waveguide, the dominant mode is defined as the propagation mode with the lowest cutoff frequency.

Now let's consider a structure in which the lowest cutoff frequency occurs for two different propagation modes (for instance TE10 and TM10): in this case, which is the dominant mode? Will exist both simultaneously?

Comment: Can you name an example of a waveguide where the lowest TE and lowest TM modes have the same cutoff frequency? If no (practical) waveguide has this property, then why worry about which mode is called "dominant"?

Comment: If you consider for instance a square waveguide with perfect electric conductor around, you get the same cutoff frequency for TE[mn] and TE[nm]. It is minimum for TE[10] and TE[01]

Comment: 1.That's a polarization degeneracy. Which mode propagates will depend how you feed the line. 2. That's why we more often use non-square rectangular waveguide.